# How to apply cart rules directly on Order?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, programmatically

I have added a `BIN promotion` which is needed to be applied just before payment directly on order.

I have found 2 methods that apply discount but require a `quote` object.

`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator::canApplyDiscount`

`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator::process`

Have anyone directly applied on the `order` object?

Comment: In Magento 2, the order model is a barely changeable quote representation that should not be manipulated manually after placement. This approach could saves you from the hassle of collecting totals and arranging invoices. I suggest to manipulate your quote just before placing instead of the order itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Magento already supports this function.

You can create cart price rules on the Magento admin page.

Log in to your Admin panel and navigate to Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rule.